# AndroidX's Edge to Edge shows an Action Bar - How to hide it?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, edge-to-edge

I've implemented `Edge to Edge` in my Android app, I've set the Status/Navigation bars to be transparent, and it works well. However suddenly an `ActionBar` appeared on top of my screen, even though I've set the app theme to be `"android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar"`. How can I fix that?

[image]

**MainActivity:**

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        enableEdgeToEdge(
            statusBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.light(
                Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.TRANSPARENT
            ),
            navigationBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.light(
                Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.TRANSPARENT
            )
        )
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
```

Root composable:

```
...
val view = LocalView.current
if (!view.isInEditMode) {
    SideEffect {
        val window = (view.context as Activity).window
        window.statusBarColor = Color.Transparent.toArgb()
        WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = !darkTheme
    }
}
...
```

**themes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.TestApp" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" />
</resources>
```

Comment: I've also had this problem, which seems to be related to specific @Composable functions.

Answer (score 4):

Have you used the [SplashScreen API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/window/SplashScreen) in your code? If you have used this API, in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file, when the theme of the starting activity is set at position **2**, the ActionBar will be displayed. However, according to the [official guide](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen/migrate#:%7E:text=In%20the%20manifest%2C%20replace%20the%20theme%20of%20the%20starting%20activity%20to%20the%20theme%20you%20create%20in%20the%20previous%20step.), both approaches are expected to have the same effect. It's puzzling that placing it at **2** displays the ActionBar while **1** does not.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to solve this for hours and no solutions worked, since I use the new Splash API, I fixed it by replacing enableEdgeToEdge() before installSplashScreen() and it worked.